# Group array elements

Tags: arrays, matlab, sorting

I have the following array: `A = [2 7 8 9 10]` and I'm looking for a way to group its subsequent elements, so to get a result like `B = [1 2; 4 7]`, where the first column returns the number of subsequent elements, and the second the value of the first element.

How do you suggest to approach the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
idx = find([[0 diff(A)] ~= 1 1]);
B = [diff(idx); A(idx(1:end-1))].';
```

The logic is this:

You're interested to know when a subsequent sequence starts. You could use the [diff](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/diff.html) function to calculate the difference between each element and the previous one, like this:

```
>> A = [2 7 8 9 10]
>> diff(A)
ans =
     5     1     1     1
```

We want to focus on values different than 1 (because they are within a sequence). The 5, in this case, represents the start of the 7,8,9,10 sequence. Also, the first element **always** start a sequence. We may "force" this by adding a 0 to the response, like this:

```
>> [0 diff(A)]
ans =
     0     5     1     1     1
```

Now, we need to get the numbers different than 1:

```
>> [0 diff(A)] ~= 1
ans =
     1     1     0     0     0
```

As we want to know the **length** of the sequence, it would be interesting to know the end of the last sequence. For that, we add a 1 in the end:

```
>> [[0 diff(A)] ~= 1 1]
ans =
     1     1     0     0     0     1
```

Now we use [find](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/find.html) to get the indexes of the 1's:

```
>> idx = find([[0 diff(A)] ~= 1 1])
ans =
     1     2     6
```

It tells us we have two sequences: the first one starts on 1 and ranges from 1..2-1, and the second one starts on 2 and ranges from 2..6-1. If we do a diff of idx, we get the lenghts:

```
>> diff(idx)
ans =
     1     4
```

To get the values, we index `A` using `idx` (ignoring the last value):

```
>> A(idx(1:end-1))
ans =
     2     7
```

The last line just combines this into a row matrix, and transposes it:

```
>> B = [diff(idx); A(idx(1:end-1))].'
ans =
     1     2
     4     7
```

Comment: Great that works! Could you explain me in one line the logic you used? I'm pretty curious now :p

Comment: Glad it worked! :) Sure, I'll edit my answer including the logic behind it.

Comment: I've edited my answer, and modified it a bit for more clarity.